# Is blood "batel beshishim"?

Tags: cooking-bishul, bitul-batel-null

I ask this question because I notice what seems to be a practical "contradiction".

Inevitably, even after salting meat, there seems to be some blood in it. Yet, I notice some people that eat raw meat (steak tartare, for example. As a child, I sometimes ate raw ground beef.)

However, when baking cake, I have been instructed to crack each egg into a glass to check for blood spots. If an egg has one, I have to dispose it. Why can't I use that egg if I will be baking the cake using a dozen eggs in the batter, and I have checked all the others and verified that there are no spots in the others?

Comment: Is the red blood visible in the taaroves?